MUI composite two components using Typescript
I want to create a component in React with MUI (using Typescript) which is the composition of two other components:

Typography (from MUI)
Translate (From https://github.com/sealninja/react-i18nify)

I would like this custom component can receive props from both, e.g.
<TypographyTranslate variant='caption' value='common.hello' />

I defined my custom component prop using typescript intersection
import { Typography, TypographyProps } from '@mui/material'
import { Translate, TranslateProps } from 'react-i18nify'

interface ITypographyTranslate {
  props: TypographyProps | TranslateProps
}

export const TypographyTranslate = ({ props }: ITypographyTranslate) => {
  return (
    <Typography {...props}>
      <Translate {...props} />
    </Typography>
  )
}

but I get this error when using the component
Type '{ variant: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITypographyTranslate'.
  Property 'variant' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITypographyTranslate'.

And the Translate in my custom component complains that all the props from Typography don't exist
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TranslateProps): Translate', gave the following error.
    Type '{ align?: "center" | "left" | "right" | "inherit" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; classes?: (Partial<TypographyClasses> & Partial<...>) | undefined; ... 372 more ...; component?: ElementType<...> | undefined; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Translate> & Readonly<TranslateProps>'.
...
...

is really possible to do composition this way?

Considering how the types look like, I really recommend to keep the props separated.

I think the issue might:

Typecasting to TypographyProps | TranslateProps but your
component expects to handle both Typography and Translate props simultaneously.
You're spreading all the props to both Typography and Translate, which causes conflicts because both components expect different sets of props.

Try changing to below and try
import { Typography, TypographyProps } from '@mui/material';
import { Translate, TranslateProps } from 'react-i18nify';

type TypographyTranslateProps = TypographyProps & TranslateProps;

export const TypographyTranslate: React.FC<TypographyTranslateProps> = ({ variant, value, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Typography variant={variant} {...props}>
      <Translate value={value} />
    </Typography>
  );
};


 

